# An incomprehensible expression.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was working on the universal coefficients theorem and it relation with the Betti number, when i came across this $\operatorname{dim}_{ \Bbb Q }$ $H_n(X;\Bbb Q)$ .
Can someone please explain me what " $\operatorname{dim}_{ \Bbb Q }$ " means exactly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The symbol $\text{dim}_{\Bbb Q}$ represents dimension over $\Bbb Q$. So $\text{dim}_{\Bbb Q}\, H_n(X;\Bbb Q)$ is the dimension of $H_n(X; \Bbb Q)$ as a $\Bbb Q$-vector space.